# Initialize array to use mysql output outside loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, initialization

Why the `print_r` don't output any data?

```
 $host = array();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $host = parse_url($row['url'], PHP_URL_HOST); 
  //echo $host;
  echo "<br>";
  }

print_r($host);
```

What is the correct way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$host[] = parse_url($row['url'], PHP_URL_HOST); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$host = parse_url($row['url'], PHP_URL_HOST);
```

For this:

```
$host[] = parse_url($row['url'], PHP_URL_HOST);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php